# Content of two site help pages: writing a good question vs. on-topic content

Tags: discussion, site-organization, asking-questions

I have noticed lately quite a few questions from new users that are unfortunately unanswerable because they do not contain enough detail, or code, or data. Rather than re-hashing the usual comments ("please include data!" etc), I was looking for a long-form explanation of how to ask a good question in the site's help pages.

That's when I noticed that, in my opinion, there is a discrepancy between the title and contents of these two help pages for our site:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

In particular, after a brief mention of what is on-topic in the first paragraph, the text within the "What topics" page describes, in excellent detail, **how to formulate a good question** (description of problem, including code, how to format, latex etc).

However, that is content I would have expected under "How to ask a good question"; instead, *that* page is rather generic in its advice.

Am I misunderstanding the two headings? If not, should we then change the contents of those pages (in essence, move the "how-to" material from "what topics" to "how do I ask")?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me.

Comment: You made a good point, but mods can only modify `/help/on-topic` ("What topics..") page, not `/help/how-to-ask` ("How do I ask...", which is generic to all SE sites)

Comment: @Andrew You are right that the how-to-ask page is the same *almost* everywhere; the only two instances of a customized `/help/how-to-ask` page I found are the ones for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). Apart from becoming one the largest sites on StackExchange ;-) , I wonder what we would need to do to get ours adjusted as well. I still find it weird that the "How to ask a good question" page does not actually contain any *site-specific* information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: You raise a good point.  I think to some extent it is countered by the fact that **What topics can I ask about here?** is the *first* question on that page, and a user might be reasonably expected to read it if they read any of them.  Would you consider it useful to have "What is a good question?" or similar as a large title within the **What topics can I ask about here?** page?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I think your suggested change would be useful for the use case I have in mind, i.e. pointing inexperienced question writers to it. I was not aware of the fact that “How to ask a good question” is not under this community’s control when I asked this question.